# How do I add a string index signature to an existing Array?

Tags: typescript

I'm working in styled-system and am trying to type a pattern that is repeatedly used in that library.

```js
const space: { [key: string]: string } = [
  '0.25rem',
  '0.5rem',
  '1rem',
  '2rem',
  '4rem',
  '6rem',
];

space.xs = space[0];
space.sm = space[1];
space.md = space[2];
space.lg = space[3];
space.xl = space[4];
space.xxl = space[5];
```

I'm getting this error:

```js
Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type '{ [key: string]: string; }'.
  Index signature is missing in type 'string[]'.ts(2322)
```

I'm not certain on how to reconcile a number key and a string key for an Array index or how to merge the object and array. It works as expected in vanilla javascript. The easy work around is setting `string` to `any` but I would like to know why this doesn't work as expected. I would think that an associative array pattern would be acceptable.

Comment: isn't space sort of a dictionary? it's missing key, that's what I think its complaining for. All values may be kept in a string[] then assignment through that array to xs/sm/md should do it.

Comment: So, you have the map those in order to actually add them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Short Answer

To add types to your existing JavaScript code, the following approach works.

Here it is [in the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=18&pc=22#code/C4TwDgpgBAggTnAhiACnA9mAzlAvFAJQgGN04ATAHgCIAPLaqAHymqwFtGXr3yvWANgHN%20dAaNq1xAGihZgcAJYA7IQD4A3AChQkWAmQB1RcAAWaTDnzylqgNoBdKADIoKRHGCLEAyvCSoGNiaWlqkyvJyYIjEEABc%20gHGZhbYeFB2WlCsAAwAdABMAKxwEJzSWbl5JWXUFdnUAIyl5ZXUBS11bQAsnfWsAGydWg7aWljRsXn06RMxEHY5o%20OTEHkcs6t2jctzU7yb83YFu6t5woexdgDMp-PTApcL3XdTko-WW0WjQA).

```
type Props = Record<"xs" | "sm" | "md" | "lg" | "xl" | "xxl", string>;
type ArrayWithProps = string[] & Partial<Props>;

const space: ArrayWithProps = [
  "0.25rem",
  "0.5rem",
  "1rem",
  "2rem",
  "4rem",
  "6rem"
];

space.xs = space[0];
space.sm = space[1];
space.md = space[2];
space.lg = space[3];
space.xl = space[4];
space.xxl = space[5];
```

### Details

First we define `Props` using the `Record` type. The `Record` type is a built-in type that defines an index signature. In our case, the equivalent index signature looks like this:

```
type Props = {
  [K in "xs" | "sm" | "md" | "lg" | "xl" | "xxl"]: string;
};
```

This index signature works (where `[K in string]` does not work), because we are using string literal types instead of the wider `string` type.

Next, we create a type named `ArrayWithProps`. This union combines the properties of the `string[]` type with the properties of the `Props` type. We use `Partial` to make each of the `Props` optional.

The result passes type checking, and it leaves the existing JavaScript code unchanged.

Comment: That's a pretty neat attempt. Also new to me :)

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation!

Comment: You're welcome @jango. Welcome to StackOverflow. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Object notation is incorrect.

`{ [key: string]: string }` means an object, where keys and values are strings. But in fact you have an array of strings.

So the correct notation will be:

```
const space: string[] = [
  '0.25rem',
  '0.5rem',
  '1rem',
  '2rem',
  '4rem',
  '6rem',
];
```

P.S. if you want to keep it as object then you need something like this

```
const space: { [key: string]: string } = {
  xs: '0.25rem',
  sm: '0.5rem',
  md: '1rem',
  lg: '2rem',
  xl: '4rem',
  xxl: '6rem',
};
```

Comment: How do you assign the short hand objects then (i.e. xs)?

Comment: @jango check out updated answer, but it is not 100% clear what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: Yeah, but then you'd not be able to do `space[0]`. Shaun had a great implementation which was exactly what I needed.

Comment: @jango you should know that assigning props to an array is actually poor solution and leads to an unexpected behavior. it is allowed by the language, but it does not mean you should do that

Comment: For example those props are not included while looping through `for`

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript uses static typings and type checking at compile time. Therefore assigning a `string[]` to `{ [key: string]: string }` does not work and hence the error. If you want to use an object, you could do something like:

```
const space: { [key: string]: string } = {};

for (const s of ['0.25rem', '0.5rem', '1rem', '2rem', '4rem', '6rem']) {
  space[s] = s;
}

console.log(space);

// { 0.25rem: "0.25rem", 0.5rem: "0.5rem", 1rem: "1rem", 2rem: "2rem", 4rem: "4rem", 6rem: "6rem" }
```

**Edit:**

You could use a `Map`:

```
const map: Map<string, string> = new Map([
  ['xs', '0.25rem'],
  ['sm', '0.5rem'],
  ['md', '1rem'],
  ['lg', '2rem'],
  ['xl', '4rem'],
  ['xxl', '6rem']
]);

console.log(map.get('xs'));
// 0.25rem

console.log(Array.from(map.values()));
// ["0.25rem", "0.5rem", "1rem", "2rem", "4rem", "6rem"]
```

Comment: Sadly, that doesn't work for us because we need the Array functions to be available for `styled-systems`. It uses both formats as a way to responsively adjust the css in our codebase.